# How can I do extend logical volume on lvm raid 5

Tags: lvm, raid5

Sorry about my broken/bad english...

I have 3TB 4 disks on lvm2, and created lv with raid 5.

I added new 2 disks on my volume group and tried to extended lv. but it wont work.

Here is my vg status.

```
# vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg2
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        5
  Metadata Sequence No  43
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                5
  Act PV                5
  VG Size               13.65 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              3576980
  Alloc PE / Size       2861584 / 10.92 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       715396 / 2.73 TiB
  VG UUID               h5w1kW-pdym-Na7U-dRHf-9Xk5-NX3F-GA19Uf
```

Here is my lv status .

```
# lvs
  LV   VG   Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv2  vg2  rwi-a-r--- 8.19t  
# lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg2/lv2
  LV Name                lv2
  VG Name                vg2
  LV UUID                aaC9Qc-1Yev-rfyh-fzZh-K32v-nRsj-Bf3msZ
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time , 
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                8.19 TiB
  Current LE             2146185
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     1024
  Block device           253:8
```

Here is `lvextend` execute result.

```
# lvextend -v  -l +100%FREE /dev/vg2/lv2
    Converted 100%FREE into at most 715396 physical extents.
  Using stripesize of last segment 64.00 KiB
    Archiving volume group "vg2" metadata (seqno 43).
    Extending logical volume vg2/lv2 to up to 10.92 TiB
    Found fewer allocatable extents for logical volume lv2 than requested: using 2146185 extents (reduced by 715395).
  Size of logical volume vg2/lv2 unchanged from 8.19 TiB (2146185 extents).
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_3 table (253:7)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_3 (253:7) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 table (253:6)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 (253:6) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_2 table (253:5)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_2 (253:5) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 table (253:4)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 (253:4) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_1 table (253:3)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_1 (253:3) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 table (253:2)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 (253:2) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_0 table (253:1)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_0 (253:1) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 table (253:0)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 (253:0) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2 table (253:8)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2 (253:8) identical table reload.
    Not monitoring vg2/lv2
    Suspending vg2-lv2 (253:8) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rimage_3 (253:7) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 (253:6) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rimage_2 (253:5) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 (253:4) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rimage_1 (253:3) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 (253:2) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rimage_0 (253:1) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 (253:0) with device flush
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_3 table (253:7)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_3 (253:7) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 table (253:6)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 (253:6) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_2 table (253:5)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_2 (253:5) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 table (253:4)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 (253:4) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_1 table (253:3)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_1 (253:3) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 table (253:2)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 (253:2) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_0 table (253:1)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_0 (253:1) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 table (253:0)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 (253:0) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2 table (253:8)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2 (253:8) identical table reload.
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rimage_3 (253:7)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 (253:6)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rimage_2 (253:5)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 (253:4)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rimage_1 (253:3)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 (253:2)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rimage_0 (253:1)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 (253:0)
    Resuming vg2-lv2 (253:8)
    Monitoring vg2/lv2
    Creating volume group backup "/etc/lvm/backup/vg2" (seqno 44).
  Logical volume lv2 successfully resized.
```

How can I extend my lv?

---

Updated

I tried to override allocation policy, but its same.

```
# lvextend -v --alloc normal  -l +100%FREE /dev/vg2/lv2
    Converted 100%FREE into at most 715392 physical extents.
  Using stripesize of last segment 64.00 KiB
    Archiving volume group "vg2" metadata (seqno 52).
    Extending logical volume vg2/lv2 to up to 10.92 TiB
    Found fewer allocatable extents for logical volume lv2 than requested: using 2146188 extents (reduced by 715392).
  Size of logical volume vg2/lv2 unchanged from 8.19 TiB (2146188 extents).
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_3 table (253:7)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_3 (253:7) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 table (253:6)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 (253:6) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_2 table (253:5)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_2 (253:5) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 table (253:4)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 (253:4) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_1 table (253:3)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_1 (253:3) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 table (253:2)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 (253:2) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_0 table (253:1)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_0 (253:1) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 table (253:0)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 (253:0) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2 table (253:8)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2 (253:8) identical table reload.
    Not monitoring vg2/lv2
    Suspending vg2-lv2 (253:8) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rimage_3 (253:7) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 (253:6) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rimage_2 (253:5) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 (253:4) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rimage_1 (253:3) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 (253:2) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rimage_0 (253:1) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 (253:0) with device flush
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_3 table (253:7)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_3 (253:7) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 table (253:6)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 (253:6) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_2 table (253:5)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_2 (253:5) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 table (253:4)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 (253:4) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_1 table (253:3)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_1 (253:3) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 table (253:2)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 (253:2) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_0 table (253:1)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_0 (253:1) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 table (253:0)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 (253:0) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2 table (253:8)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2 (253:8) identical table reload.
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rimage_3 (253:7)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 (253:6)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rimage_2 (253:5)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 (253:4)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rimage_1 (253:3)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 (253:2)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rimage_0 (253:1)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 (253:0)
    Resuming vg2-lv2 (253:8)
    Monitoring vg2/lv2
    Creating volume group backup "/etc/lvm/backup/vg2" (seqno 53).
  Logical volume lv2 successfully resized.


# vgs -oname,vg_attr,extendable
  VG   Attr   Extendable
  vg2  wz--n- extendable
```

I changed lv allocation policy, but `lvextend` says still insufficient extents..

```
# lvchange --alloc normal vg2/lv2
  Logical volume "lv2" changed.

# lvs
  LV   VG   Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv2  vg2  rwn-a-r--- 8.19t                                    100.00   
# lvextend -v --alloc normal  -l +100%FREE /dev/vg2/lv2
    Converted 100%FREE into at most 715392 physical extents.
  Using stripesize of last segment 64.00 KiB
    Archiving volume group "vg2" metadata (seqno 52).
    Extending logical volume vg2/lv2 to up to 10.92 TiB
    Found fewer allocatable extents for logical volume lv2 than requested: using 2146188 extents (reduced by 715392).
  Size of logical volume vg2/lv2 unchanged from 8.19 TiB (2146188 extents).
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_3 table (253:7)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_3 (253:7) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 table (253:6)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 (253:6) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_2 table (253:5)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_2 (253:5) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 table (253:4)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 (253:4) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_1 table (253:3)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_1 (253:3) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 table (253:2)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 (253:2) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_0 table (253:1)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_0 (253:1) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 table (253:0)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 (253:0) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2 table (253:8)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2 (253:8) identical table reload.
    Not monitoring vg2/lv2
    Suspending vg2-lv2 (253:8) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rimage_3 (253:7) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 (253:6) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rimage_2 (253:5) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 (253:4) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rimage_1 (253:3) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 (253:2) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rimage_0 (253:1) with device flush
    Suspending vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 (253:0) with device flush
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_3 table (253:7)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_3 (253:7) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 table (253:6)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 (253:6) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_2 table (253:5)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_2 (253:5) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 table (253:4)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 (253:4) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_1 table (253:3)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_1 (253:3) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 table (253:2)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 (253:2) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rimage_0 table (253:1)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rimage_0 (253:1) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 table (253:0)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 (253:0) identical table reload.
    Loading vg2-lv2 table (253:8)
    Suppressed vg2-lv2 (253:8) identical table reload.
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rimage_3 (253:7)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rmeta_3 (253:6)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rimage_2 (253:5)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rmeta_2 (253:4)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rimage_1 (253:3)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rmeta_1 (253:2)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rimage_0 (253:1)
    Resuming vg2-lv2_rmeta_0 (253:0)
    Resuming vg2-lv2 (253:8)
    Monitoring vg2/lv2
    Creating volume group backup "/etc/lvm/backup/vg2" (seqno 53).
  Logical volume lv2 successfully resized.
```

**EDIT**

Here is `pvdisplay` result. `/dev/sdb1` is *allocatable*

```
# pvdisplay 
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdg1
  VG Name               vg2
  PV Size               2.73 TiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              715396
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          715396
  PV UUID               QzjE6n-FRSj-NloW-ejFv-B0i0-lfqn-1O03Vu

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdc1
  VG Name               vg2
  PV Size               2.73 TiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              715396
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          715396
  PV UUID               bwFwkf-d2zz-1TQR-PR11-IsgN-0P2n-BYMhfW

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sde1
  VG Name               vg2
  PV Size               2.73 TiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              715396
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          715396
  PV UUID               fWnIz6-Jgf3-QpPW-VKvr-Od1H-cFAp-UrQe6E

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdf1
  VG Name               vg2
  PV Size               2.73 TiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              715396
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          715396
  PV UUID               e5rd2D-Xsh8-HD93-KVDs-TtPC-2sM1-i1AROl

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name               vg2
  PV Size               2.73 TiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              715396
  Free PE               715392
  Allocated PE          4
  PV UUID               SrIKSJ-RzON-Kelu-rC0O-8rLd-rIpI-Fkd1BW
```

Comment: Your problem seems similar to this  [Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/829372/37681) - The allocation policy for your logical volume is "inherit" - display the policy for the volume group with [`vgs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/vgs) and check the vg_attr bits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insufficient suitable allocatable extents when extending lvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/829372/insufficient-suitable-allocatable-extents-when-extending-lvm)

Comment: @alexander-tolkachev@HBruijn Thanks about your replies. I thought that link was possible solution to me. but its not. I updated result.

Comment: I'm only seeing 5 physical volumes after your vgextend. Should I not be seeing 6 (four original and two new)? More space is better for reshape, and RAID-5 needs a fair amount of "head room".

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M I removed 1 disk from vg because i got same result when I first tried `lvextend` added 2 new disk on vg2.

Comment: "Inherit" allocation policy really should work fine here. Could you post the output of `pvdisplay`? It sounds like the PVs you've added aren't allocatable.

Comment: @Spooler I updated `pvdisplay` result, target PV is _allocatable_

Comment: Please don't do R5 with those disks anyway, not if you like your data

Comment: @Chopper3 I plan to change raid 6 after adding 2 disks

Answer (score 1):

I realize lvm does not support raid type change from raid 5 to raid 6.

I was planned to change raid 5 to raid 6 after added 2 disks.

Now I changed my plan.

1. Delete datas on lv which are i can recover from other storage.
2. Create degraded mdadm raid 6 storage with 3 or 4 disks.
3. Move all data from lvm raid 5 to degraded raid 6 storage.
4. Destory lvm raid and all lvm disk add to degraded raid 6.
5. Rebuid raid 6 storage and retrive deleted data.

I'm not sure this plan is good or not, anyway now I know lvm raid is not a good choice manage storage.

I will close my post my struggle is over. ;)

Comment: I'm completed change from lvm builtin raid 5 to mdadm raid 6. It was almost took 4 days for rebuilding and reshaping raid 6 also retrieving data which was I deleted for resizing lvm raid 5. I learnt one lesson. DO NOT USE LVM BUILTIN RAID.